# DSM Web station - Deploying a symfony project using containerized (docker) service

Tags: php, docker, symfony, nginx, synology

Since I have DSM 7.2 installed, I wanted to give the new containerized script language service a chance.

I have a working symfony 6.2 project and I wanted to deploy this to my NAS in the most simplest way possible.

Here's what I did:

1. Open web station -> Web service
2. Create -> Containerized script service
3. Set document root to /volume1/web/project1/public
4. I enabled a few extensions, picked mariadb as my database driver, and left all other settings to default

After everything compiled, I have a new project in DSM's new Container Manager.
This is the docker file it created for that project:

```
services:
  php:
    build: .
    labels:
      com.webstation.type: php
    sysctls:
      net.core.somaxconn: 65535
    volumes:
      - /var/packages/WebStation/etc/php_profile/8b95b6ab-21a9-488d-9408-8ffc4f657232:/usr/syno/etc/packages/WebStation/php_profile/8b95b6ab-21a9-488d-9408-8ffc4f657232
      - /run/docker-share:/run/docker-share
      - /volume1/web/project1/public:/home/php/src
      - /volume1/web/project1:/home/php/
  database:
    image: mariadb:10.11@sha256:b11a86131ac592eaabede175b3547d12d2c96d63c71936af28217ffc3bb3fee2
    volumes:
      - /var/services/web_packages/docker/mariadb/tongil:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: tongil
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: supersafe_user123
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: yes
```

The problem I'm facing is that:

```
  - /volume1/web/project1/public:/home/php/src
```

Only the public folder gets copied into /home/php/src, omitting symfony's code.
I can't change this volume, because container manager will complain that this value should be exactly what it says.

I thought an easy fix would be to add a new line that copies the entire project to /home/php:

```
  - /volume1/web/project1:/home/php/
```

That didn't work out of the box, so I've tried:

1. Change php's `doc_root` setting to `/home/php/src` and `/home/php`
2. Ran `composer dump-autoload` and `bin/console cache:clear --env="prod"` after changing `doc_root`

If my doc_root is set to `/home/php`, I get a white page with the text `No input file specified.`. Otherwise, I get a symfony error pages saying that it can't find `/home/php/vendor/autoload_runtime.php`. This really should point to `/home/php/src/vendor/autoload_runtime.php`

Manually changing nginx config doesn't appear to be a good idea in DSM, but the conf file for my project refers to these:

```
include /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/052337a9-2a3e-4e85-aafc-78b9c4534fbd/fastcgi.conf*;
include /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/052337a9-2a3e-4e85-aafc-78b9c4534fbd/user.conf*;
```

I tried redefining in `user.conf` where nginx should point to by changing:

```
root    "/volume1/web/project1/public";
```

to

```
root    "/volume1/web/project1";
```

But it doesn't like me doing that at all :)

Can someone push me in the right direction?